# Where is my unexpected T_STRING?

Tags: php, eval

Ordinarily, one would expect that the unexpected T_STRING implies a missing semicolon. However, in this case, where's the semicolon missing from??

```
        global $lay;
        $yal = eval("return '$lay';");
        echo $yal . "\n";
```

The error is thrown in the eval, viz

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in ... BOGARIP.php(140) : eval()'d code on line 1
```

with $lay containing

```
$reportDate\t$heads['Account']\t$id\t$heads['Time zone']\t$heads['Campaign']\t$heads['Ad group']\t$heads['Network']\t$heads['Network (with search partners)']\t\t$heads['Ad group state']\t$heads['Campaign state']\t$heads['Impressions']\t$heads['Clicks']\t$heads['CTR']\t$heads['Avg. CPC']\t$heads['Avg. CPM']\t$heads['Cost']\t$heads['Avg. position']
```

Does this imply that the bug is actually in $lay or am I missing something else? Is this level of string substitution even possible?

Comment: Don't do this! It's madness.. Can you at all refactor your code to not use eval?

Comment: You really shouldn't be doing this, but just out of curiosity, can you swap the quotes in your eval statement to `eval('return "$lay";');` and see if that has any effect?

Comment: What are you trying to do? It's impossible to give a suggestion without more context.

Comment: @boost I've provided the solution in the answer below. Glad we could help you out with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Took @Evert's advice and refactored. Now the format contains

```
%DATE%\t%Account%\t%ID%\t%Time zone%\t%Campaign%\t%Ad group%\t%Network%\t%Network (with search partners)%\t\t%Ad group state%\t%Campaign state%\t%Impressions%\t%Clicks%\t%CTR%\t%Avg. CPC%\t%Avg. CPM%\t%Cost%\t%Avg. position%
```

and the code

```
    $heads["ID"] = $id;
    $heads["DATE"] = $reportDate;
```

...

```
    global $lay;
    $layout = $lay;
    foreach ($heads as $key => $value) {
        $layout = str_replace("%" . $key . "%", $value, $layout);
    }
    $layout = str_replace("\\n", "\n", $layout);
    $layout = str_replace("\\t", "\t", $layout);
```

Answer (score 2):

You really shouldn't be doing anything with `eval`, generally speaking. But, for the sake of the technical issue here, consider the following:

```
eval("return '$lay';");
```

You're surrounding the `$lay` variable with single quotes. Now let's look at the contents of this variable:

```
$reportDate\t$heads['Account...
```

See the problem? You're using single quotes within the value too. Swap out the quotes in your eval statement so there is no longer a conflict:

```
eval('return "$lay";');
```

Again again, please don't use this code. By and large, professionals will steer you away from every using `eval`, as it opens up your application to a great deal of potential woes. Please find another way to do whatever it is you're attempting.

Comment: I appreciate the time you took with that. Thanks.

Comment: @boost Answers aren't only for the OP. Somebody else may have the same problem some day. These posts get better mileage than we know I'm sure ;)